The way that/the way in which
According to the Oxford dictionary, we can use both "the way in which" and "the way that".
For example:

It's not what you say, it's the way that you say it.

or

New technology has radically changed the way in which this work is
done.

Could anyone please explain to me what the difference is between these two constructions?
One forum seems to suggest that these constructions are interchangeable (see post #14).
But is it always so?
Can I say, for example:

It's not what you say, it's the way in which you say it.

or

New technology has radically changed the way that this work is
done.

I also wonder which construction should I use in the following sentence:

I'm quite proud of the way in which/the way that my eyes turned out in this
picture (an artist is talking about his self-portrait).

I thank you very much in advance!

It will sound more natural if you omit the relative pronoun: "It's the way you say it"

For most purposes as a learner, you'd probably be better of not using either of the way in which and the way that. Keep things simple, and just use how.

This edit is important for your level: [Could anyone please explain to me what the difference is between these two constructions?]

I

It's not what you say, it's the way that you say it.

The use of the pronoun "that" can only be considered, in this sentence, to be made in the objective case; "that" as subject would make no sense, and there are just two possibilities: objective  and subjective case. This is the key to the reasoning. Since "that" has "way" for antecedent, the rendering preserving the relation involved is "you say it the way". Notice, however, that in this construction you end up with two objects, "it" and "the way". Two objects is not a possibility associated with the verb "to say". "It" is a natural object, there is no problem with this idea; it must be then that "the way" is not found in the sentence in an object relation with the verb "to say" and is an adverbial of this verb, in fact an adverbial of manner. A small digression is necessary in order to show that in English an adverbial of manner is not necessarily implemented by an adverb ("slowly", "intentionally", "frugally", etc) nor by a prepositional phrase ("with deliberate slowness", "with a firm intention", "in a display of frugality", …), but can also be materialized by means of a plain noun phrase. Below, in the n-gram I selected the verb "do", more prone to such a usage, but as well "say", and the the determiner "this", that latter, again because of the propensity shown by this determiner to such a use, but it is clear that the relation is an adverbial one, and not that of object. The n-grams to follow make clear that the absence of a preposition is not the rule.



If in the context of independent clauses the "tampering" with grammatical relations insofar as the omission of prepositions is concerned, can attain to some sort of grammatical legitimacy (but let us remember, "you said it in a way", and not "you said it a way"), I am not so favourable to transplanting this practice—which is but a tentative one for the time being— in the context of relative clauses, where the grammatical word "that" overwhelmingly confers the idea of an object relation, and which, I think, should be preserved as doing that only. In conclusion, I consider "the way in which" as perfectly grammatical, whereas "the way that" is in this context a form of very dubious grammaticality.
II

New technology has radically changed the way in which this work is done.

The discussion to be found above should be  conducive  to the conclusion that there is no problem concerning this construction.
III

It's not what you say, it's the way in which you say it.

There is no question that this is a perfectly grammatical sentence; this has been discussed above.
IV

I'm quite proud of the way in which/the way that my eyes turned out in this picture (an artist is talking about his self-portrait).

In the sense "turn out" has to be taken in this sentence, it is not a transitive phrasal verb, but an intransitive one; however, adverbials of manner (or of an other kind for that matter) are not a "predilection" of transitive verbs, and the problem remains the same as that discussed above.


in which (phrase)
“In which” (= that … in) is a phrase (comprising the preposition “in”
plus relative pronoun “which”) to provide the functionality of a relative pronoun.

[Robert C Lee; Grammarly]
Compare

the cupboard where the plates are
the man that the dog bit
the shelf on which the CDs are
the field in which the cows are
the ways in which we express ourselves [metaphorical usage]
the ways that we let ourselves down [metaphorical usage]

In each case, the relativiser (where and other wh-words; that) or equivalent (on/in/under/above ... which) introduces an independent clause or noun phrase plus verb, requiring a complement, and together these postmodify the noun or noun phrase, usually definingly.
The actual expressions 'the way/s that' and 'the way/s in which' are fixed phrases.
'The way that/in which you speak' = 'Your manner of speaking'.
There is a look-alike usage which needs that:

the way that leads to destruction
the ways [that] we find to avoid paying Income Tax
The way that we choose (ie our chosen route/method)

but these, on closer analysis, are seen to be different.
For the relevant examples, I'd say that there is a large overlap in meaning,  and basic acceptability, for both variants, but that there is a register difference: 'the way in which' is more formal than 'the way that'.
So I'd tend not to choose

the way/s in which John really gets up Joe's nose
the way/s that telic and atelic activities differ

as using juxtapositions somewhere along the incongruity continuum. Though the strings are not ungrammatical.
This line from the song 'The Way You Say It' (note that 'that' can even be deleted) by Jan Nigro / Vitamin L]

The way that you say it, uh-huh, oh yeah!

would certainly not work well with the more formal variant.
There is also polysemy with both 'the way in which' and 'the way that'.

I like the way in which / that / Ø she does her hair

almost certainly refers to the hairstyle rather than the activity.

I like the way in which / that / Ø you walk

almost certainly refers to the activity.

I like the way that / Ø you showed Jill how to solve that maths problem

can refer to either the methodology chosen or the willingness to help.

Dear @Edwin Ashworth, thank you so much for your detailed answer. I don't know why, but unfortunately, this page allows me neither to accept your answer nor to mark your answer as useful. It must be due to some problems with the site...
